# Conectar PHP con SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql

He buscado por todos lados, pero no encuentro respuesta o encuentro respuestas incompletas.

¿Cuál es la manera completa de conectar PHP con SQL Server 2008?

Comment: ¿Has probado con PDO? En la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) (en inglés) tiene un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo

Comment: Viene la manera de como hacerlo , pero hay que hacer cosas extras, descargar un driver, configurarlo y no se que más es lo que no encuentro

Comment: No se mucho de esto, pero acá te dejo este video en Inglés que capaz te ayuda https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72XCFF4YiOw

Comment: Hola Guillermo, he visto que esta pregunta tiene 10k visitas... alguna respuesta te ha servido? recuerda marcarla como aceptada

Comment: depende del driver que quieras usar: en php hay multiples opciones de driver (Controladores de coneccion a base de datos y cada driver tiene una manera y un soporte distinto para cada tipo de base de datos) https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8755/46896

Comment: Antes de todo eso tiene que descargar el driver https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567 para la conexión y seguir los pasos de PieroDev o mejor aun seguir esto pasos que me funcionaron https://www.saotn.org/install-microsoft-sql-server-driver-php/.

Answer (score 8):

Primero debes descargar el Driver o dll de sql Server y configurarla como se muestra en el enlace de abajo, es sencillo y sólo te tomará unos 10 minutos hacerlo:
[Driver PHP SQLServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296203%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Posteriormente intenta con:

```
 resource sqlsrv_connect ( string $serverName [, array $connectionInfo ] )
```

Abre una conexión a una base de datos Microsoft SQL Server. Por defecto, la conexión se intenta utilizando la autenticación Windows. Para conectar utilizando la autenticación SQL Server, incluir "UID" y "PWD" en el array de opciones de conexión.
Parámetros

serverName

```
El nombre del servidor en el que se ha establecido una conexión. Para conectar a una instancia específica, poner una barra invertida después del nombre de servidor e indicar el nombre de la instancia (e.g. NombreServidor\sqlexpress).
```

connectionInfo

```
Un array asociativo que especifica las opciones de conexión al servidor. Si no se ha especificado ningún valor para el UID y PWD, la conexión se intentará utilizando la autenticación Windows. Para una lista completa de claves soportadas, ver » Opciones de Conexión SQLSRV.
```

Valores devueltos

Un recurso de conexión. Si no se puede abrir la conexión, se retorna el valor FALSE .
Ejemplos

Ejemplo #1 Conectar utilizando autenticación Windows.

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName

// Puesto que no se han especificado UID ni PWD en el array  $connectionInfo,
// La conexión se intentará utilizando la autenticación Windows.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Ejemplo #2 Conectar especificando nombre de usuario y contraseña.

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Ejemplo #3 Conectar a un puerto específico.

```
<?php
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress, 1542"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (por defecto es 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Notas

Por defecto, la función sqlsrv_connect() utiliza la conexión mediante agrupación para mejorar el funcionamiento de la conexión. Para desconectar el funcionamiento en modo grupo (p.ej. forzar una nueva conexión en cada llamada), configurar la opción "ConnectionPooling" en el array $connectionOptions a 0 (o FALSE). Para más información, ver » Cola de conexión SQLSRV.

La extensión SQLSRV no tiene una función específica para cambiar a que base de datos se está conectado. La base de datos objetivo se especifica en el array de opciones $connectionOptions que se pasa a sqlsrv_connect. Para cambiar la base de datos en una conexión ya abierta, ejecutar la siguiente sentencia sql "USE dbName" (p.ej. sqlsrv_query($conn, "USE dbName")).

Answer (score 4):

En mi experiencia, he utilizado [**PDO (PHP Data Object)**](http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) para realizar la conexiones a bases de datos **MySQL y SQL SERVER**.

*PDO_DBLIB* es el controlador que implementar SQL Server en PHP.

La ventaja de PDO en este caso, es que acepta 12 gestores de bases de datos. 
La desventaja comparándolo con el [Microsoft Driver PHP for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn865013(v=sql.105).aspx), es que este es más afinado, o eso tengo entendido.

En lo extendido, las propiedades de conexión con la base de datos, suelen estar en php en un fichero llamado **db_config.php**, este será mi fichero para presentarte el ejemplo de conexión.

**db_config.php**

```
<?php

define("DRIVER_SQL", "dblist:host");
define("DATABASE", "ejemplo");
define("PORT",     "10060");
define("HOSTNAME", "localhost");
define("USERNAME", "admin");
define("PASSWORD", "1234");


define("URI", DRIVER_SQL . HOSTNAME . ":" . PORT . ":dbname=" . DATABASE);

?>
```

Y este el fichero, donde tendrás consultas preparadas y/o realizarás la conexión.

**db.php**

```
<?php

// ...

function connect() {
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO(URI, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo("PDOException: ".$e);
            return false;
    }
}

// ...

?>
```

Aquí encontrarás muchos ejemplos de conexión: [Enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-dblib.php)

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de que tu servidor de aplicaciones este en linux, te recomiendo que uses [FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/) que es una libreria nativa que conversar con sql server y que es mucho mas rapido que otras librerias.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno la idea es instalar correctamente el driver para php.

En Ubuntu es con freetds  apt-get install freetds-bin freetds-common freetds-dev - See more at: http://blog.espol.edu.ec/nemo/2014/07/30/conexion-odbc-entre-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-con-sql-server-utilizando-freetds/#sthash.qDICxJCE.dpuf

En Centos es el mssql-php5

Bueno asi de rapido deberias basarte en buscar dirver sql linux (distribución) mssql

De ahí mayormente todas las conexiones son iguales

```
$conexion=mssql_connect($serverName,$uid,$pwd);

mssql_select_db($base_datos,$conexion);
```

Comment: `mssql_` está obsoleto en `PHP7`, lo correcto sería con `odbc_connect`:  http://php.net/manual/es/function.odbc-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Mi hermano espero que esta solucion te ayude.

Instalate el xampp de esta version :

https://www.google.com.pe/search?q=xampp&oq=xampp&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61l3j0l2.2485j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

una vez instalada descargate estos dll.

```
php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

una vez instalada te vas en tu xampp

CONFIG - > PHP.INI

Y agregas esto

```
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
;extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

ahora cuando ya hayas colocado te vas aen tu disco C luego xampp luego php luego dll y los dll que te habias descargado lo pegas ahi.

y seria todo.

luego pruebas con la conexión.

para que conectes de tu sql server a tu php

```
<?php
$serverName = '';
$uid = 'sa';
$pwd = '';
$databaseName = 'dbdatos';
$connectionInfo = array( 'UID'=>$uid,'PWD'=>$pwd,'Database'=>$databaseName);



$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);


if($conn){echo ''; }else{echo 'Connection failure<br />';die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),TRUE));}


?>
```

espero verte ayudado.

Comment: ¿Y si el driver de sqlserver no existe en el servidor? creo recordar que ese driver no viene por defecto en la distribución...

Comment: @efrein claro no viene por defecto tiene que descargarte php_sqlsrv  y  php_pdo_sqlsrv y colocarlo en tu dll

Answer (score -2):

A mi me funcionó con este código:

```
$servidor = "NOMBREPC\SQLEXPRESS";
$database = "PRUEBA";
$info = array('Database'=>$database);
$cn = sqlsrv_connect($servidor, $info);
```